# jQuery untoggle menu on new toggle

Tags: jquery, menu

I have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9J5Fg/

When one box is open and I click on the other one, I would like to open box to close and then the other box opens.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/9J5Fg/2/

Or the nice and clean css3 version http://jsfiddle.net/9J5Fg/3/

Comment: Try to click again the link, you will see that it doesn't close.

Comment: Works perfectly! I didn't even think of using CSS3, which I'll probably use, since I don't need to support IE on this project. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a single click event to handle this ..
Just add the class to both the div's and it should work fine..

**JS**

```
$('#tb1 , #tb2').click(function() {
    $('#box-1, #box-2').stop().animate({"height": '0px'}, 400);

    if ( $('#' + this.className).height() == 0) {
        $('#' + this.className).stop().animate({ "height": '50px' }, 400);
   }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="btns">
    <span id="tb1" class="box-1">Toggle box-1</span>
    <span id="tb2" class="box-2">Toggle box-2</span>
</div>
```

​[CHECK DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/mZRRa/1/)

Comment: There is a problem with it though, if you click while it's animating down it will not switch direction, mine does :), anyway well done.

Comment: I'm really impressed with how clean it is. If it wasn't for the little bug mentioned by xception, I would have marked this with the green check mark. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what you need :)

First of all you have to identify which link is being clicked and what box this link refers. After that you can toggle it's height.
Then you have to close the others.

```
$('#tb2, #tb1').click(function() {
    var id = this.id.substr(-1),
        $box = $('#box-' + id),
        height = $box.height();

    // toggle box height
    $box.stop().animate({"height": (height == 50 ? 0 : 50) + 'px'}, 400);
    // close other boxes
    $('#container div').not($box).stop().animate({"height": '0px'}, 400);
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NE3HV/)

If you look [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GuxAg/1/) you will see that this code works if you have more than 2 boxes, you just have to change the click selector to `$('#btns span')`.

Answer (score 1):

a bit more abstracted.. could be coded even better if you are willing to change your html

```
$('#btns span').on('click', function () {

    var btnId = $(this).attr('id'),
        $container = $('#box-' + btnId.substr(2)),
        open = $container.height() > 0;

    $('#container div').not($container).stop(true, true).animate({"height": '0px'}, 400);

    $container.stop(true, true).animate({"height": (open ? '0px' : '50px')}, 400);
})
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/9J5Fg/5/

Comment: update. you didn't make clear that you want it to be closed again.

Comment: He posted that comment on mine, I didn't know at first either. Oh, and it's not my question, I just passed on the info. I'll remove my previous comment though. Didn't mean any offense.